# docker-compose swarm: force containers to run on specific hosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Trying to run cluster application on different virtual machines with use of Swarm stand alone and docker-compose version '2'. Overlay network is set. But want to force certain containers to run on specific hosts.

In documentation there is following advice, but with this parameter I was not able to start any container at all:

```
environment:
  - "constraint:node==node-1"

ERROR: for elasticsearch1  Cannot create container for service elasticsearch1: Unable to find a node that satisfies the following conditions
[available container slots]
[node==node-1]
```

Should we register hosts as node-1 node-2... or it is done by default.

```
[root@ux-test14 ~]# docker node ls
Error response from daemon: 404 page not found
[root@ux-test14 ~]# docker run swarm list
[root@ux-test14 ~]#  

[root@ux-test14 ~]# docker info
Containers: 8
 Running: 6
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 8
Server Version: swarm/1.2.5
Role: primary
Strategy: spread
Filters: health, port, containerslots, dependency, affinity, constraint
Nodes: 2
 ux-test16.rs: 10.212.212.2:2375
  â ID: JQPG:GKFF:KJZJ:AY3N:NHPZ:HD6J:SH36:KEZR:2SSH:XF65:YW3N:W4DG
  â Status: Healthy
  â Containers: 4 (4 Running, 0 Paused, 0 Stopped)
  â Reserved CPUs: 0 / 2
  â Reserved Memory: 0 B / 3.888 GiB
  â Labels: kernelversion=3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64, operatingsystem=CentOS Linux 7 (Core), storagedriver=devicemapper
  â UpdatedAt: 2016-09-05T11:11:31Z
  â ServerVersion: 1.12.1
 ux-test17.rs: 10.212.212.3:2375
  â ID: Z27V:T5NU:QKSH:DLNK:JA4M:V7UX:XYGH:UIL6:WFQU:FB5U:J426:7XIR
  â Status: Healthy
  â Containers: 4 (2 Running, 0 Paused, 2 Stopped)
  â Reserved CPUs: 0 / 2
  â Reserved Memory: 0 B / 3.888 GiB
  â Labels: kernelversion=3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64, operatingsystem=CentOS Linux 7 (Core), storagedriver=devicemapper
  â UpdatedAt: 2016-09-05T11:11:17Z
  â ServerVersion: 1.12.1
Plugins:
 Volume:
 Network:
Swarm:
 NodeID:
 Is Manager: false
 Node Address:
Security Options:
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64
Operating System: linux
Architecture: amd64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.775 GiB
Name: 858ac2fdd225
Docker Root Dir:
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
```

Comment: Print the output of `docker run swarm list` to see your node names.

Comment: Oh, also please clarify that you're asking about the legacy Docker Swarm, not the new "Swarm mode".

Comment: added missing info in question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My first answer is about "swarm mode". You'd since clarified that you're using legacy Swarm and added more info, so here:

The constraint you list assumes that you have a host named `node-1`. Your hosts are named `ux-test16.rs` and `ux-test17.rs`. Just use that instead of `node-1` in your constraint. Eg:

```
environment:
  - "constraint:node==ux-test16.rs"
```

Answer (score 6):

The **environment variable** `constraint` is only valid for the legacy (stand alone) version of Swarm. The newer "Swarm Mode" uses either `mode` or `constraints` options (not environment variables).

To enforce one and only one task (container) per node, use `mode=global`.

```
docker service create --name proxy --mode global nginx
```

The default mode is `replicated` which means that the swarm manager will create tasks (containers) across all available nodes to meet the number specified in the `--replicas` option. Eg:

```
docker service create --name proxy --replicas 5 nginx
```

To enforce other constraints based on hostname (node), label, role, id's use the `--constraint` option. Eg:

```
docker service create --name proxy --constraint "node.hostname!=node01" nginx
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#/specify-service-constraints

EDIT sept 2016:

Something else. `docker-compose` is not currently supported in "swarm mode". Swarm mode understands the new [`dab`](https://blog.docker.com/2016/06/docker-app-bundle/) format instead. There is a way to convert docker-compose files to dab but it's experimental and not to be relied on at this point. It's better to create a bash script that calls all the `docker service create ...` directly.

EDIT March 2017:

As of docker 1.13 (17.03), docker-compose can now be used to provision swarm environments directly without having to deal with the dab step.

Comment: Sorry I have forgot to specify that I am using stand alone swarm, not the command supported in new docker version. The reason I use old version is because it do not support docker-compose unless you install docker experimental version.

Comment: I don't have any legacy warm environment setup but your constraint should work assuming that you have a host named `node-1`. I really suggest that you move to "swarm mode". The time spent converting your docker-compose file to a dumb bash or Makefile is still worth since you'll save untold effort not having to setup Consul, TLS, and other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I am running elasticserch cluster with swarm, were nodes are not identical copies but communicate with each other and some are master some client/data nodes. I ma not sure is this feasible and is it too complicated without docker-compose

Comment: `--constraint "node.hostname!=node01"` helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Related issue - I had a recent Swarm project with a mixture of worker nodes (3 x Linux + 4 x Windows). My containers needed to run on a specific OS, but not on any specific node. Swarm mode now supports specifying an OS under "constraints" in docker-compose files. No need to create labels for each node:

```
version: '3'  
services:  
    service_1:  
        restart: on-failure  
        image: 'service_1'  
        deploy:  
            placement:  
                constraints:  
                    - node.platform.os == windows  
    junittestsuite:  
        restart: on-failure  
        image: 'junit_test_suite:1.0'  
        command: ant test ...  
        deploy:  
            placement:  
                constraints:  
                    - node.platform.os == linux
```